# Merge several data frame, keep only one set of colnames

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using a package which for each element in a list, print in a file the following lines:

```
Entry   Entry name  Status  Protein names   Gene names  Organism
A0A20CSC4   A0A20CSC4_1PHYC unreviewed  Uncharacterized protein OlL7_200    Ostreococcus lucimarinus virus 7

Entry   Entry name  Status  Protein names   Gene names  Organism
A0A0P0DZ8   A0A0PCDZ8_9PLYC unreviewed  Uncharacterized protein OlL7_159    Ostreococcus lucimarinus virus 7

Entry   Entry name  Status  Protein names   Gene names  Organism
A0A1P0BY71  A0A1P0BY71_9PHYC    unreviewed  Uncharacterized protein OlL7_111c   Ostreococcus lucimarinus virus 7
```

... X 1000

so if I open this file with pandas I get a data frame such as:

```
>>> blast
        Entry        Entry name      Status            Protein names  Gene names
0   A0A20CSC4   A0A20CSC4_1PHYC  unreviewed  Uncharacterized protein    OlL7_200
1         NaN               NaN         NaN                      NaN         NaN
2   A0A0P0DZ8   A0A0PCDZ8_9PLYC  unreviewed  Uncharacterized protein    OlL7_159
3         NaN               NaN         NaN                      NaN         NaN
4       Entry        Entry name      Status            Protein names  Gene names
5  A0A1P0BY71  A0A1P0BY71_9PHYC  unreviewed  Uncharacterized protein   OlL7_111c
```

and I would like to create only one data frame with the colnames:

```
Entry   Entry name  Status  Protein names   Gene names  Organism
A0A20CSC4   A0A20CSC4_1PHYC unreviewed  Uncharacterized protein OlL7_200    Ostreococcus lucimarinus virus 7
A0A0P0DZ8   A0A0PCDZ8_9PLYC unreviewed  Uncharacterized protein OlL7_159    Ostreococcus lucimarinus virus 7
A0A1P0BY71  A0A1P0BY71_9PHYC    unreviewed  Uncharacterized protein OlL7_111c   Ostreococcus lucimarinus virus 7
```

Do you know a method using pandas in python3?

updated data frame:

```
        Entry        Entry name      Status            Protein names  Gene names
0   A0A20CSC4   A0A20CSC4_1PHYC  unreviewed  Uncharacterized protein    OlL7_200
2   A0A0P0DZ8   A0A0PCDZ8_9PLYC  unreviewed  Uncharacterized protein    OlL7_159
4       Entry        Entry name      Status            Protein names  Gene names
5  A0A1P0BY71  A0A1P0BY71_9PHYC  unreviewed  Uncharacterized protein   OlL7_111c
```

row 4 still have the row names.

Comment: What code are you using to create the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one way to get that type of output is if you drop NaN values.

So you could do,
`blast.dropna(inplace=True)`

`blast.drop(blast[blast['Entry'] == 'Entry'].index, inplace=True)`

This should work.

Comment: Yes I know but I still keep the row with the row names, I updated the result in the command to show you.